# Add JavaScript if User Device Screen is Small

Tags: javascript

how to add script when screen is smaller than 992px and i want add this. this is the illustration.

```
if ($(window).width() < 992px) {      
    var today = new Date();
    var hourNow = today.getHours();
    var greeting;

    if (hourNow >= 0) {
        greeting = "Good Morning"; 
    }

    else if (hourNow >= 18) {
        greeting = "Good Evening"; 
    }

    else {
        greeting = "Welcome"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What you mean by "add javascript"? Btw, calling `$(window).width()` you will get just an number, so comparing to `992px` is invalid code.

Comment: Did my code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
if (window.innerWidth < 992){
  // Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react to the window size change, you should handle the `resize` event of the `window` object, using jquery like this:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var w = $(this).width();
  // Check the window width
  if(w < 400) {
    $("#output").get(0).innerHTML = "Device screen is small.";
  }
  else {
    $("#output").get(0).innerHTML = "Device screen is large.";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```